# Cloudways needs reset permissions on new files

Tags: symfony, cloudways

I am using Symfony 3.2 on Cloudways server. The issue is in cache. I want clear cache on each push as symfony in prod env does not update twig cache. However cache can not be cleared because of file permissions. New files (cache) have wrong permissions so that I cannot delete them. The only way is to reset permissions in application settings in Cloudways admin. But it is a headache to do it on each push. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hi, Yes the permission issue was there. But I didn't see the issue since morning, I cleared cache and sessions many times and it's working good without resetting permissions.

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz what framework do you use?

Comment: Symfony 3.2 and 3.0

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz maybe you did some actions to prevent the issue? Do you remember what you did before the issue disappeared? Between, I chatted with support and they said that there is no workaround

Comment: I've hated Cloudways for this same reason. The file permissions are a persistent issue, and the Cloudways "support" team has no idea about how file permissions work. Cloudways has a lot of trouble with my simple Laravel app. I look forward to moving off of Cloudways.